# Find the most recently updated rows according to a multi-column grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server and T-SQL.

**Sample Data:**

I have data similar to the following readily consumable test data.

```
--===== Set the proper date format for the test data.
    SET DATEFORMAT dmy
;
--===== Create and populate the Test Table
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable
;
 CREATE TABLE #TestTable
        (
         Item       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
        ,GroupA     TINYINT     NOT NULL
        ,GroupB     SMALLINT    NOT NULL
        ,Updated    DATE        NOT NULL
        ,Idx        INT         NOT NULL
        )
;
 INSERT INTO #TestTable WITH (TABLOCK)
        (Item,GroupA,GroupB,Updated,Idx)
 VALUES  ('ABC',7,2020,'14/11/2019',8)  --Return this row
        ,('ABC',7,2020,'10/11/2019',7)
        ,('ABC',6,2019,'14/11/2019',6)  --Return this row
        ,('ABC',5,2018,'13/11/2019',5)  --Return this row
        ,('ABC',5,2018,'12/11/2019',4)
        ,('ABC',7,2018,'14/11/2019',3)  --Return this row
        ,('ABC',7,2019,'25/11/2019',2)  --Return this row
        ,('ABC',7,2019,'18/11/2019',1)
;
--===== Display the test data
 SELECT * FROM #TestTable
;
```

**Problem Description:**

I need help in writing a query that will return the rows marked as "--Return this row". I know how to write a basic SELECT but have no idea how to pull this off.

The basis of the problem is to return the latest updated row for each "group" of rows.  A "group" of rows is determined by the combination of the Item, GroupA, and GroupB columns and I need to return the full rows found.

Comment: [How do I ask a good **question**?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry about that, I am new and shall go through the instruction .. thank you.

Comment: I rewrote your post to give you an example of how to ask a more clear question and how to help others help you by providing readily consumable data.  Please take the time to review it and to understand it.

Comment: Now that I've rewritten the OP's post to meet the requirements of how to post, could someone reopen this post so that I can add a solution, please?

Comment: Thank you good folks for reopening this post but I have to ask about the edit... what's wrong with a polite thank you in advance on a post?

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by item, groupa, groupb order by updated desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table.Item,table.GroupA,table.GroupB,table.Updated,Idx
FROM    (select Item,GroupA,GroupB,max(Updated) Updated
         from table 
         group by Item,GroupA,GroupB) a
inner join table 
on(a.Item = table.Item and a.GroupA = table.GroupA and a.GroupB = table.GroupB and 
   a.Updated = table.Updated)
```